# Play Encrypted Video Files from Android Device's Local Storage

Tags: video, streaming, encryption

We are searching for ways to play encrypted video files on an Android device such that a user cannot extract the files via USB cable or other methods to a computer and play them. We'd like the decryption to happen as the video is playing unless there is a fast way to do it right before playback starts. Some of our video content will be greater than 4GBs and we will be encrypting them ourselves so we'll have access to the algorithm/key/salt. We'd like follow similar standards as Netflix and other large streaming media providers even though our content will be preloaded on the device.

Comment: If you preload the file on the target device and do the decryption locally, the user has as well the algorithm/key/salt and if dedicated enough, can transfer the preloaded movie and decrypt is afterwards. If you store it in the local storage, you do not have control over it anymore what the user can do with it

Comment: Thanks @Zibelas! We're actually planning on streaming the video locally, not preloading it, so that the player only has access to chunks of it at a time. We're okay with someone capturing the video via screen-capture as that's impossible to prevent.